# Problem with creating a Serial queue in Swift using GCD

Tags: swift, swift3

I am implemented Serial queue like Bellow

```
var serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.serial.queue")
```

and using like this

```
serialQueue.sync(execute: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2.0) {
                print("First Task")

            }
        })



serialQueue.sync(execute: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.0) {
                      print("Second Task")
                  }
            })
```

**Expected:**  first task, Second Task

**But it prints:** Second task, first task

Answer (score 0):

It's because in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` call you delay printing "Second Task" one second and printing "First Task" 2 seconds.
So after 1 second you get "Second Task" and after another 1 second "First Task".

You can call print directly in serialQueue or if you need do this in main thread, just remove the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var time = DispatchTime.now() + 0.2

serialQueue.sync(execute: {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
            print("First Task")
        }
    })


time = time + 0.1

serialQueue.sync(execute: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
                  print("Second Task")
              }
        })
```